# how to post data ajax using php

Tags: php, ajax

How to post data into insert php file it can't post data

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#insert').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (strmessage) {
                $('#message').text(strmessage)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
?>
<p id="message"></p>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"><br>
    <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="insert" name="insert" value="insert">
</form>
```

Comment: what is the problem while posting?

Comment: you should use `enctype="multipart/form-data`

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you tried catch data in *insert.php*?

Comment: @developersaumya `enctype` is not required here. OP's not sending any file with the form.

Comment: in insert.php  only this much print_r( $_POST);

Comment: yes enctype is not required

Comment: make sure the path is correct in ajax

Comment: Everything is working as expected, with `print_r($_POST)` it will print `Array ( [name] => your name [email] => your email [contact] => your contact )`.

Comment: Make sure the file path in the `url` is correct.

Comment: @user6171329 use script below form , it will work

Comment: yes it should be return array but what is problem in my code

Comment: @user6171329 why you event.preventDefault(); before the ajax call ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To submit your form from jquery ,you should write your jquery code in `body` element and under `form` element will be more easy to handle ...

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</script>
<body>
<?php
?>
<p id="message"></p>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"><br>
    <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="insert" name="insert" value="insert">
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#insert').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (strmessage) {
                $('#message').text(strmessage)
            }
        });
    });
   </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: i have told you same in my comments @user6171329 :)

Answer (score 0):

In insert.php file fetch data like this:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
echo $name."--".$email."--".$contact;
?>
```

Comment: still dose not return anything

Comment: Please make sure the path is correct in ajax..have you checked console?? any error occuring in ajax request??

Answer (score 0):

In server side i.e in php you have echo or print any message for ajax return otherwise ajax not return anything.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#insert').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        method: "post",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (strmessage) {
            $('#message').text(strmessage);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $contact = $_POST['contact'];

  //do whatever want do by these value 

  print_r($_POST);

//here you have to echo or print the any message for ajax return otherwise ajax not return anything 

  ?>
```